# couldn't figure out the issue with angular routing / ng-repeat.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angular-template

The **aboutus.html** page is displayed correctly, except the content in the **ng-repeat** within **media-list** in **aboutus.html**.  there are no errors displayed in the console. I have not included the entire code (since it takes more space.). Can anyone help me?

```
      // factory here. 
      angular.module('vasuapp')

     .factory('corporateFactory', function() {

    // Implement two functions, one named getLeaders,
    // the other named getLeader(index)
    // Remember this is a factory not a service

    var corpfac = {};

    var leadership = [
        {
          id: 0,
          name:"asdfd",
          designation:"sgsdgg",
          abbr: "fgdfvf",       
        },
        {
           // similarly some other data here.   
        } ];

     corpfac.getLeader = function(){
     return leadership;
    };
    corpfac.getLeaders = function(index)
    {
        return leadership[index];
    };
    return corpfac;

});

    // app.js 
 angular.module('vasuapp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/aboutus', {templateUrl:'./aboutus.html' , controller: 'AboutController'})
        .otherwise('/');
})

   // controller.js 

 angular.module('vasuapp')
     .controller ('AboutController',['$scope','corporateFactory', function($scope,corporateFactory){
   var leadership = corporateFactory.getLeader();
    $scope.leaders = this.leadership;
}])

     // aboutus.html 

   <div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
        <p> hi </p>
        <ul class="media-list">
            <li class = "media" ng-repeat = "lead in leaders">
               <div class = "media-list tab-pane fade in active">
                <a ng-href="#/aboutus">
                    <img class = "media-object" ng-src={{lead.image}} alt="author image">
                </a>
               </div>
                <div class = "media-body">
                <p>{{lead.description}}</p>
                </div>
             <footer>
                 -- {{lead.name}} the {{lead.designation}}
                 </footer>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear, and you haven't really stated what you are expecting, but from a quick glance it seems like you are trying to use `var leadership` and `this.leadership` interchangeably, but they aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

`$scope.leaders = corporateFactory.getLeader();`

`this.leadership` is not defined.